# React: Environment variables returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables

I have tried to access to the environment variables in two ways and in both I've got the same result. The environment variable is "undefined".

**First way**

I have follow these steps:

1. I have installed the module "env-cmd"
2. I have created a root file called .env.development with this content:

   BACKEND_PROTOCOL = http

   BACKEND_DOMAIN = localhost

   BACKEND_PORT = 4000
3. In the script to start my application I have modified with this commands:

`"env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts start"`

4. I try to get the value with:

console.log(`${process.env.BACKEND_PROTOCOL}://${process.env.BACKEND_DOMAIN}:${process.env.BACKEND_PORT}`);
console.log(process.env.BACKEND_PROTOCOL);

5. I start the development server with:

   env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts start

I have follow this instructions: [enter link description here](https://dev.to/samirasaad/environment-variables-for-a-react-js-app-329j)

**Second way**

1. I have installed dotenv module
2. I have created in the root a file called .env
3. I have filled this file with these values:
   BACKEND_PROTOCOL = http

   BACKEND_DOMAIN = localhost

   BACKEND_PORT = 4000
4. I make an import of dotenv with:

   import config from "dotenv";
5. Before to get access to the variables I call to config and the I try to get the values of the environment:

   config.config();
   console.log(`${process.env.BACKEND_PROTOCOL}://${process.env.BACKEND_DOMAIN}:${process.env.BACKEND_PORT}`);
   console.log(process.env.BACKEND_PROTOCOL);
6. I start my development server with this intructions:

   react-scripts start

And I've got the same result. I've got undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think you need to append your env variable with REACT_APP_{YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME}

Comment: OMG!!! I forgot the prefix for the name of the variables!!! Thank you very much for your appreciated help!!!

Comment: Documentation: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/